# HttpContext Moq outside of controller in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit

I want to moq HttpContext in .net core 1.0.0 for test case

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<string> Login(string email, string password)
{
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
   {
       return HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
   }
   else
   {
       return "";
   }
}
```

Here is my test case

```
[Fact]
public async Task Login()
{
     ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "siddhartha@promactinfo.com", Email = "siddhartha@promactinfo.com", Name = "siddhartha" };
     await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Something@123");
     var userAdded = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
     var result = await Login("siddhartha@promactinfo.com", "Something@123");
     Assert.Equal("siddhartha", result);
}
```

It goes fail, gets error message:

> HttpContext must not be null.

Here is my service - startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PromactOauthDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(x => x.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter(_loggerFactory)));
    }
```

Comment: I didn't notice this at first, but is your Fact test method and your actual Login method in the same class?  How is the test calling Login directly without creating a Controller?  If you are not creating the controller, you can't pass in the mocks.

Answer (score 2):

Without using controller. I have moq HttpContext in .net core. And used HttpContext in repository

Register HttpContext in test case project like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{       
        var authenticationManagerMock = new Mock<AuthenticationManager>();
        var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        httpContextAccessorMock.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns("Siddhartha");
        httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Authentication).Returns(authenticationManagerMock.Object);
        var httpContextAccessorMock = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        httpContextAccessorMock.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(httpContextMock.Object);
        var httpContextMockObject = httpContextAccessorMock.Object;
        services.AddScoped(x => httpContextAccessorMock);
        services.AddScoped(x => httpContextMockObject);
        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

Then you will get HttpContext.User.Identity.Name = Siddhartha

```
public async Task<string> Login(string email, string password)
{
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    else
    {
         return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that error is from a null check on the SignInManager's constructor.  I cant see how you built your SignInManager for your tests so I cannot be sure if you passed something in or not, but I suspect not.

If that is the case, create a mock of IHttpContextAccessor and setup the HttpContext property to return a new DefaultHttpContext() then pass that mocked object into the SignInManager.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I tried but still not working. @Runesun

Comment: You'll need to provide more code then.  I can't tell how you build up your manager dependencies (namely SignInManager) in the code provided.